# Add points if someone checks checkbox html

Tags: javascript, html, express

I need help, I want this page to add one point on every check, but this code isn't doing what i quite expect.. Even i check all 3 its only adds 1 ( I know its because of if else logic ), but is there any way around it, or any solution:

Here's my Code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { 

res.send(`
        <form method='POST' action='/test'>
            Work<input type="checkbox" name="a1" /><br>
            Gym<input type="checkbox" name="a2" /><br>
            Go out<input type="checkbox" name="a3" /><br>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' /><br>
        </form>
        `)
})

var points = 0

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {

    const a1 = req.body.a1
    const a2 = req.body.a1

    if (a1) {
        points += 1
    }
    else if (a2) {
        points += 1
    }
    else if (a3) {
        points += 1
    }


    console.log(points)
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

You can also tell me jquery but i should be able to add points to a specific varible in backend

Comment: Well remove the `else` keyword in both places then …?

Comment: Just remove the `else` and keep the three distinct `if`. So that they will all be executed and each one will add its `1` point.